# Bulk API maximum field length measure in Java

Tags: bulk-api, csv

I'm using Bulk API on Java to insert EmailTemplate records. Some errors that were caught were:

```
InvalidBatch : Failed to parse CSV. Exceeded max field size: 51112
```

However, the record in question had the max field length of around 95798. How does Salesforce mark this particular field of length as 51112? There are no other fields that exceed the maximum limit of 32000 characters.

To validate my concern on the character count, some records with the max field size of around 35000 while another record got accepted with the field length of around 55000. This is quite confusing on how to approach in Java. Obviously, String.length() is not the exact measure.

If I have to skip the records that would fail on Bulk upload, I have to arrive at this number as computed by Salesforce more accurately. Already tried a few options like (the current approach is not accurate):

```
int maxFieldLen = 32000;
String field = csvRecord.getField(fieldName);
int fieldLen = 0;
// fieldLen = field.length(); 95798
// fieldLen = field.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length(); 95798
fieldLen = field.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1_8).length(); 95798
if(fieldLen > maxFieldLen)
 continue;
```